# findViewById vs getChildAt - which one is quicker?

Tags: android, performance, android-view, findviewbyid

Acquiring a view in the hierarchy I have both of these functions available. While [findViewById](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) is easier to use, I often saw suggestions that it can be an expensive operation and should be avoided if possible.

Therefore, would it be any quicker to use [getChildAt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt(int)) instead? Is there any guideline as to when it is better to use which?

Comment: `"I often saw suggestions"` ignore them

Comment: i guess findViewById() is quicker, just accessing the particular views with ID's. easier to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> findViewById vs getChildAt - which one is quicker?

`getChildAt` is indeed faster than `findViewById`, since it is just accessing an array of `View`s at the specified `index`.

> Therefore, would it be any quicker to use getChildAt instead

it will indeed, but you have to know the `index` of the `View` you are looking for. If you don't have any mechanism to keep track of the index, than you have to look for it, and you got back to `findViewById`. You will probably ended up re writing your own version of `findViewById`. My two cents, don't worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `ViewGroup` implementation `findViewById` will eventually loop through children and compare id so I suggest to just use the `findViewById`method.

```
@Override
protected View findViewTraversal(@IdRes int id) {
    if (id == mID) {
        return this;
    }

    final View[] where = mChildren;
    final int len = mChildrenCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        View v = where[i];

        if ((v.mPrivateFlags & PFLAG_IS_ROOT_NAMESPACE) == 0) {
            v = v.findViewById(id);

            if (v != null) {
                return v;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```